# Cannot resolve method super in class which extends ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In the android app I am creating, I have a scrollable tabs and in one of those fragments I am trying to display all the user downloaded apps.

I am trying to implement this using a fragment

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-in-android

My application class extends Fragment. The class is used to initialize and list the installed applications. As getting the list of application details from PackageManage is a long running task.

Also, this class is using ApplicationAdapter class which extends ArrayAdapter.

My ApplicationAdapter class received this error.

[image]

I am trying to figure out why super is unable to be resolved and how to fix it. Shouldn't it be called at the beginning?

Here is my java code for the ApplicationAdapter class:

```
package com.javatechig.listapps;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledAppActivity;
import com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.R;

import java.util.List;







public class ApplicationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ApplicationInfo> {
    private List<ApplicationInfo> appsList = null;
    private InstalledAppActivity context;
    private PackageManager packageManager;

           public ApplicationAdapter(InstalledAppActivity context, int textViewResourceId,
                                          List<ApplicationInfo> appsList) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, appsList);
        this.context = context;
       this.appsList = appsList;
        packageManager = context.getActivity().getPackageManager();
      }

            @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.size() : 0);
       }

           @Override
    public ApplicationInfo getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != appsList) ? appsList.get(position) : null);
        }

           @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
        }

            @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getActivity().
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.snippet_list_row, null);
            }

        ApplicationInfo data = appsList.get(position);
        if (null != data) {
           TextView appName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_name);
           TextView packageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_package);
            ImageView iconview = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);

            appName.setText(data.loadLabel(packageManager));
            packageName.setText(data.packageName);
            iconview.setImageDrawable(data.loadIcon(packageManager));
           }
        return view;
        }
};
```

If it is any use to show my fragment class here it is:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.javatechig.listapps.ApplicationAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class InstalledAppActivity extends Fragment {
    private PackageManager packageManager = null;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> applist = null;
    private ApplicationAdapter listadaptor = null;

    ListView InstalledAppList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        packageManager = (PackageManager) getActivity().getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        new LoadApplications().execute();

        InstalledAppList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ApplicationInfo app = applist.get(i);
                try {
                    Intent intent = packageManager
                            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName);

                    if (null != intent) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }

                catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }



        });
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_apps, container, false);

    }


    private List<ApplicationInfo> checkForLaunchIntent(List<ApplicationInfo> list) {
        ArrayList<ApplicationInfo> applist = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>();
        for (ApplicationInfo info : list) {
            try {
                if (null != packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                    applist.add(info);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return applist;
    }

    private class LoadApplications extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progress = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            listadaptor = new ApplicationAdapter(InstalledAppActivity.this,
                    R.layout.snippet_list_row, applist);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            //setListAdapter(listadaptor);
            InstalledAppList.setAdapter(listadaptor);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }



        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error is:**

> Cannot resolve method 'super(com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.InstalledActivity,int,java.util.List'

Comment: Please copy and paste your error rather than posting a screenshot. The easiest way to do this is to go to the Problems view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that `InstalledActivity` does not extend/implement `Context`, therefor it does not apply to any of the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor clauses.

Comment: @XiJiaopin Use Fragment's `getActivity()` method.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I've been trying to figure out how exactly to apply getActivity

Comment: if `Fragment` has a `getActivity()` method which returns a `Context`, then you would apply that in your super constructor above. I don't know the Fragment class off-hand, but it would basically be `super(/*your Fragment */.getActivity(), /* other args */);`

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the parameters you are trying to pass to the super constructor do not match any of the constructors for `ArrayAdapter`. Check the documentation for the available constructors.

Comment: I believe it should match... I checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

The error might be deeper than simply that